# Is there a way to have a counter for a flask application that is shared across multiple mod_wsgi threads/processes?

Tags: python, flask, mod-wsgi

I've come up with a few ways I'm pretty sure this could be achieved.

- have some sort of external data store (a file/sqlite3/pickle) plus a file locking mechanism.
- Use a [remote manager](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.managers.BaseManager) from the `multiprocessing` module

Here's a basic sample of the app I've written

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)
counter = 0

@app.route('/')
def index():
    counter += 1

    return "Counter: " + str(counter)

if __name__ == "__main__":

    app.run(debug=True)
```

Here's what the mod_wsgi configuration looks like

```
WSGIDaemonProcess app processes=2 threads=2
WSGIScriptAlias /app /var/www/apps/app.wsgi process-group=app application-group=%{GLOBAL}
```

So my question is does anyone have any experience with this kind of problem? If so what did you end up doing to solve this problem?

Comment: https://github.com/underyx/Flask-Redis

Comment: Yeah just stick it in a shared memory structure like redis. There's even an `INCR` operator in redis to do just that... http://redis.io/commands/INCR